# Replace all IP addresses in a file to a specified string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a huge list of `IP address` in a file and I want to replace all the IP address to a specified string`( Example : X.X.X.X)`.

```
#Example.txt
1,1.1.1.1
2,10.10.10.10
3,5.5.5.5
4,6.6.6.6
.........
```

I tried replacing using `sed`

```
$sed -e 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/x.x.x.x/g' example.txt
```

I couldn't achieve this. Can some one help me on how to replace the IP address with a specific string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there!  All that you have to do is escape the repetition braces:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/x.x.x.x/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks David.